# Cite author with Eurographics/CGF template

Tags: citing

I need to use the following template style:

https://www.eg.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/egPublStyle-cgf.zip

How can I cite an author using a natbib-like `\citet{}`?

---

What I got so far:

- Need to use the biblatex approach.
- Compile with biber.
- Define:
  `\DeclareRobustCommand{\citet}[1]{\citeauthor*{#1}~\cite{#1}}`
  or as @Guido pointed out, add the option `natbib=true` to `biblatex`.

However, it cites the last names of everyone, and the names are capitalized. This is because of the `"bibstyle=EG"` option passed to `biblatex`.

Comment: `biblatex` has an option (`natbib`) to emulate the `natbib` command.

Comment: Indeed: then, I have \citet. But the problem still stands.

Comment: Stefanie sent me a new EG package that supports natbib.